# NodeJS async library parallel method strange behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

I'm attempting to use the async module with NodeJS for the first time, and I'm running into a problem when I try and dynamically construct an array of functions for the async.parallel function to run:

```
    methods = [];
    for (key in entries) {
      methods.push(function(callback) {
        return callback(null, key);
      });
    }
    return async.parallel(methods, function(err, results) {
      console.log(results);
      return render_views(req, res, 'view_blog_all', {
        entries: entries
      });
    });
```

The output I keep seeing is:

```
    [ 'powerful_sms_communication_for_teams',
  'powerful_sms_communication_for_teams',
  'powerful_sms_communication_for_teams' ]
```

And my 'entries' object I'm looping over definitely has three different keys. Something I'm missing?

ASYNC MODULE:
https://github.com/caolan/async

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common problem people run into with asynchronous logic. The key is to remember that your callback will not run until you call `async.parallel`, and at that point, `key` will the last key value in the loop.

One way to solve this is to capture the key value within a new scope using an IIFE.

```
methods = [];
for (key in entries) {
  (function(key){
    methods.push(function(callback) {
      return callback(null, key);
    });
  })(key);
}
```

You can also use `async.map` with a normal array and single iterator instead.

```
return async.map(
  entries,
  function(key, callback){
    callback(null, key);
  },
  function(err, results) {
    console.log(results);
    return render_views(req, res, 'view_blog_all', {
      entries: entries
    });
  }
);
```

Comment: Ah I see, okay I'm trying to figure out the best way of adapting to that.

Comment: I'd also recommend looking at the `async.map()` docs, since you seem to be doing the same function on each array element.

Comment: I would, my example is oversimplified. I'm performing an asynchronous method for each key in my object and I want them to all run in parallel

Comment: @CaseyFlynn Try out the map, you'll notice that it's also parallel and gives you a callback to do async stuff with. It just eliminates the loop you write to create the functions.

Comment: @loganfsmyth You can delete the loop in your map example, and simply pass the entries array as the first parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a rewrite using https://github.com/caolan/async#map

```
async.map(entries, function(entry, callback) {
  //do your stuff, fully parallel and async ;)
  callback(null, entry);
}, function(err, results) {
  console.log(results);
  return render_views(req, res, 'view_blog_all', {
    entries: entries
  });
});
```